# Divide bounding box / extent into several parts in R

Tags: r, geolocation, gis

I have an extent which is shown below. The extent is in the form of a square and I would like to split the whole extent into several small squares so that I can process each small extent (square) individually. Could anyone help me with this?

```
require(raster)    
x <- extent(c(5.956135, 10.47513, 45.817936, 47.808453))
```

Comment: How would you like to split it? Please express this in your question and not as a reply to this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I found the answer by myself I am posting the answer.

```
x <- seq(1:4)
df <- data.frame(x)
xFactor <- (47.808453 - 45.817936)/length(x)
yFactor <- (10.47513 - 5.956135)/length(x)
df$xCH <- df$x*xFactor + 47.808453
df$yCH <- -df$x*yFactor + 10.47513
```

Coordinates for the split extent can be found from the output dataframe very easily.